How to Generate a Random Complex Symmetric Unitary Matrix in Python?
I am trying to optimize a complex symmetric unitary matrix
 with dimensions N*N using Python.
First of all, how to generate matrix  that should satisfies the two conditions:
=^{T}     (symmetric constraint), where ^{T} is the transpose of 
 . ^{H}= I (Unitary constraint), where ^{H} is the Hermitian transpose of  and I is the identity matrix.
Secondly, I will use it to maximize a matrix multiplication of matrix B with N*N dimensions, so how to perform this matrix multiplication while  remains both symmetric and unitary.
import random
import numpy as np
import cmath
import math

N = 4  # Matrices dimensions 

B=np.array([[0.09+0.76j, 0.67+0.08j, 0.28+0.58j],
            [0.47+0.82j, 0.85+0.07j, 0.13+0.49j],
            [0.12+0.8j , 0.35+0.31j, 0.76+0.85j]])                  

result =  A @ B


First generate random unitary matrix, then use formula from this answer to make it symmetric. There might be some better way to do this though (I am not an expert in this)

As long as your initial matrix doesn't have determinant 0 then use the Gram-Schmidt process to produce orthogonal columns (a series of operations to remove the projections of prior columns) and then make them orthonormal at the end. e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162190/how-to-convert-a-random-matrix-to-unitary-matrix

can you please provide a code example of how this is performed

First find the unitary matrix U (the bulk of the stuff below). Then
V=UTU will be symmetric and unitary.
The harder part is getting the unitary matrix U. A matrix is unitary if and only if its columns are orthonormal. (Dot products of different columns are 0; norm of each column is 1.) So you can construct such a matrix by the Gram-Schmidt process.
Imagine each column of your matrix is a vector. Dealing with each column in turn you (a) subtract the projections of previous column vectors; then (b) normalise this column. As long as you have independent columns (i.e. your original matrix was invertible) then this will produce orthonormal columns and hence a unitary matrix.
The following will produce a unitary matrix from a given matrix A. A unitary matrix is one for which the conjugate of its transpose is its inverse (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix ). It tests this at the end by multiplication to give the identity matrix (up to the usual floating-point accuracy).
You can improve this by (a) checking matrix A is invertible first (e.g. by calculating its determinant) and (b) formatting the output a bit more neatly.
import numpy as np

def makeUnitary( A ):
    N = A.shape[0]                          # number of columns
    U = A.copy()
    # Gram-Schmidt process
    U[:,0] /= np.linalg.norm( U[:,0] )      # normalise first column
    for i in range( 1, N ):                 # make successive columns orthogonal
        for j in range( i ):                #    by subtracting projections of previous columns
            U[:,i] -= U[:,i].dot( U[:,j].conj() ) * U[:,j]
        U[:,i] /= np.linalg.norm( U[:,i] )  # normalise column
    return U


A=np.array([[0.09+0.76j, 0.67+0.08j, 0.28+0.58j],
            [0.47+0.82j, 0.85+0.07j, 0.13+0.49j],
            [0.12+0.8j , 0.35+0.31j, 0.76+0.85j]])               
U = makeUnitary( A )                                  # a unitary matrix
V = U.T @ U                                           # symmetrised unitary matrix


print( "Original matrix:\n", A )
print( "\nSymmetric unitary matrix constructed from it:\n", V )
print( "\nCheck V.V(conj)T (should be identity matrix):\n", V @ V.conj().T )

Output:
Original matrix:
 [[0.09+0.76j 0.67+0.08j 0.28+0.58j]
 [0.47+0.82j 0.85+0.07j 0.13+0.49j]
 [0.12+0.8j  0.35+0.31j 0.76+0.85j]]

Symmetric unitary matrix constructed from it:
 [[-0.77181963+0.51542139j  0.15837321+0.05726809j -0.30709606+0.12635484j]
 [ 0.15837321+0.05726809j  0.40398494-0.53221372j -0.43217941-0.581725j  ]
 [-0.30709606+0.12635484j -0.43217941-0.581725j    0.55047024-0.24804427j]]

Check V.V(conj)T (should be identity matrix):
 [[1.00000000e+00-2.05296819e-18j 3.93579786e-16-6.38754713e-16j
  6.37756498e-17-6.66363810e-16j]
 [3.93579786e-16+6.24994617e-16j 1.00000000e+00-1.58327863e-18j
  1.09796762e-16-1.28773584e-16j]
 [6.37756498e-17+6.55406471e-16j 1.09796762e-16+1.49124945e-16j
  1.00000000e+00-8.89174271e-19j]]

A unitary matrix can be diagonalised (i.e. written as Q-1.diag.Q). Powers of U can then be computed quickly simply by taking powers of the elements in the diagonal matrix.

Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation, one last thing  when I show U and U.T (to see if U is symmetric) they are not equal, how to make it both unitary and symmetric?

Ah right - I should have read your requirements more carefully. Anyway, the original code simply produced a matrix that is unitary (from the invertible matrix A). Then just create a new matrix V=UT.U. Quick checks will show that this is also unitary and is symmetric.

Thank you so much for this useful insights,  I am just curious behind the reason that makes the new matrix V both unitary and symmetric from just multiplying UT.U, also I just read about the qr decomposition does taking the Q matrix from the command Q, R = np.linalg.qr(A) is similar to what you have done earlier to make it unitary? thanks again for your efforts.

Any matrix of the form MT.M is symmetric, because of the transpose of a product (A.B)T = BT.AT. For unitary you will just have to form the product (UT.U)T*(UT.U) and after a lot of multiplying out the inner bits you will get I - so, a unitary matrix. Gram-Schmidt is one way of doing a QR decomposition - actually, it's the first one I ever learnt - however it is prone to some numerical instability due to floating-point inaccuracy.
